# Is there a way to use Curve25519 Elliptic Curve encryption method on Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, backend

I want to create a public and private key using curve25519 to encrypt some data in a file. It looks like iOS has something in the CryptoKit to allow clients to build something like this below. How can I use Curve25519 encryption in an Android project? I could not find any android-specific libraries that come with it. Any suggestion on how I can do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
let albusPrivateKey = Curve25519.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
let albusPublicKeyData = albusPrivateKey.publicKey.rawRepresentation
let harryPrivateKey = Curve25519.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
let harryPublicKeyData = harryPrivateKey.publicKey.rawRepresentation
```

Comment: You can find a complete example for an key exchange using Curve25519 and AES-CBC encryption here: https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/tree/main/Curve25519KeyExchangeAesCbc256StringEncryption (Disclaimer: I'm the author). A complete Java example is here: https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/blob/main/Curve25519KeyExchangeAesCbc256StringEncryption/Curve25519KeyExchangeAesCbc256StringEncryption.java. You will need an additional library (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.whispersystems/curve25519-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Android has the [androidx.security.crypto](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security) packages  built on [Google Tink](https://github.com/google/tink#current-status).

You'll probably have to access Google Tink directly as [Curve25519](https://google.github.io/tink/javadoc/tink/1.0.0/index.html?com/google/crypto/tink/subtle/Curve25519.html) has an `Alpha` annotation signifying:

> Signifies that a public API (public class, method or field) is subject to incompatible changes, or even removal, in a future release.
> An API bearing this annotation is exempt from any compatibility guarantees made by Tink.
>
> The presence of this annotation might also indicate that the quality or performance of the API in question not ready for production.
>
> It is unsafe to depend on alpha APIs.

Answer (score 0):

```
  val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("x25519")
  val keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
```

I was able to just do this and this worked for me. This is from the Java security package.